# Tag Wars — [esql] vs [embedded-sql] vs [entity-sql] vs [extended-sql]?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is messy.

### Context

There's a tag [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) (126 questions) with a tag wiki that says "a storage-independent query language that is similar to SQL. Entity SQL allows you to query entity data, either as objects or in a tabular form".  A little bit of searching shows (suggests to a naïve outsider) that [Entity SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of Microsoft's .NET programming environment.

There is a tag [entity-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql) (56 questions) with a tag wiki that says "Entity SQL is a storage-independent query language that is similar to SQL. Entity SQL allows you to query entity data, either as objects or in a tabular form" — which is remarkably similar to the information for [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql).

There's a tag [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql) (83 questions) with a tag wiki that says it is "the term used for a method of inlining SQL statements with the source code of another programming language, called host language".

There's a tag [ibm-integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-integration-bus) (69 questions) with a tag wiki that says "IBM Integration Bus (formerly WebSphere Message Broker) is integration broker that provides connectivity and universal data transformation in heterogeneous IT environments".  The abbreviation IIB is also used for this in questions.  Many of the questions tagged [ibm-integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-integration-bus) are also tagged with [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql), but this is a mistake — they're not related to the Microsoft Entity SQL.

There isn't yet a tag [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql) with a tag wiki that says something like ["Extended Structured Query Language (ESQL) is a programming language defined by IBM® Integration Bus to define and manipulate data within a message flow"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak00990_.htm).  That would need tweaking to avoid a direct quote of the web page.

I'm not sure how many of the questions tagged [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) are actually about Microsoft's ESQL — I've not seen one yet, but I've not looked at them all.

I've retagged a few of the IBM Integration Bus questions which had the tag [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) with the tag [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql), which was a mistake in retrospect.

### Suggestion

1. Create the proposed [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql) tag with an appropriate paraphrase of its use with IIB.
2. Retag the IIB-related questions that use tag [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) with the new [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql).
3. Retag other questions tagged [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) that are about embedded SQL with the tag [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql).
4. Retag any questions about Entity SQL tagged [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) with the precise tag [entity-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql).
5. Make sure there are no questions left with the plain [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql).
6. Identify questions for IIB that were mistakenly retagged with [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql) and re-retag with [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql).
7. Update the tag wiki for [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) with "Do not use this tag.  Use one of the tags [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql), [entity-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql) or [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql) instead."  This can be done before the retagging is complete.  Once there are no questions tagged [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql), after a short while (24 hours or less), the tag will be dropped and everybody can go back to sleep again.

### Observations

I'm of the opinion that it would be a mistake to make [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) a synonym for any of the other tags — ESQL is the term used by each of the three separate groups of products, and is ambiguous.  Selecting any of them as 'the ESQL' would be somewhat presumptuous.  If it is made a synonym, it should be a synonym of [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql) — there is precedent going back to the last millennium for products such as Informix ESQL/C (Embedded SQL in C), and the SQL standard from 1992 (ISO/IEC 9075:1992) defines Embedded SQL syntax.  The Microsoft and IBM alternatives are both much more recent than that.

I stumbled on this mess when a question about Informix ESQL/C needed to be retagged.  There was briefly a tag [esql-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql-c), but I let that lapse on finding tag [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql).

### Question

Any observations about or objections to this proposed plan of action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there was no vehement objection (and precious little activity of any sort on an esoteric collection of tags) and the question only collected up-votes, I've gone ahead with most of the plan outlined:

- The [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) wiki has been updated to say "Do not use this tag" and point to the preferred alternatives.
- The [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql) has been added with a barebones wiki entry.
- The [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) has been removed from all but two questions and replaced with (what seemed to me) the most appropriate alternative of the three more specific names — [embedded-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-sql), [entity-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql) or [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql).
- There was frequently other cleanup done — there were a few cases where I didn't remove 'thanks' or other minor changes.

There are two questions left with the plain [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) tag, one of which also has an [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) tag.  It is not clear to me from the question content which of the specific tags applies (the choice is [entity-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql) or [extended-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extended-sql), probably).  So, I've added comments to the questions requesting clarification.  However, I'm not confident that either OP will notice the request, and I'm also not worried because having these two questions around preserves the [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) tag with its redirection to the preferred solutions.  It'll be easy enough to search periodically for new questions with [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) and update those appropriately.

So, I regard this as case (more or less) closed.  I can't put Trogdor here because the [esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) isn't about to burninated.

Comment: It would be nice if we could have the ability  to create sub-tags, e.g. [Informix][esql/c]. This would help prevent ambiguity since several products have similar or exact names.

Comment: It would be possible to create a tag [tag:informix-esql/c] unless `/` is not allowed in tags (which seems to be the case — in which case either [tag:informix-esql] or [tag:informix-esql-c] would be OK).  There is an upper limit on the length of tags, but I don't think these run into the problem.  More significantly, there isn't really a major reason to create it — there really aren't that many Informix questions, let alone those that need to be tagged for Informix ESQL/C (more's the pity).

Comment: Agreed on low number of Informix esql/c questions. Nevertheless, there are other products which share similar, or same names, that have caused questions to be incorrectly tagged.